# How do I return JSON with strings that contain only numbers

Tags: php, json, .net

I have a .NET app that calls an API and deserializes the response content to a List where MyClass has

```
class MyClass
{
    public int id {get; set; }
    public string name {get; set; }
    public float score {get; set; }
}
```

using

```
return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<MyClass>>();
```

I have an API written in PHP which reads the data from a MySQL database and returns them as follows:

```
$response = new Response(json_encode($resultArray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
```

Now, if I don't use JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK, all the values in the JSON get returned as strings, eg:

```
[ 
{"id":"1","name":"test","score":"3.4"},
{"id":"2","name":"1999","score":"4.8"} 
]
```

and so the deserialize fails as it can't convert a string to an int or float.

However, if I do use JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK, the above example looks like this:

```
[
{"id":1,"name":"test","score":3.4},
{"id":2,"name":1999,"score":4.8}
]
```

The name only contains numbers, so the numeric check has converted it to an int, and so the deserialize fails as it can't convert an int to a string.

Is there a correct way of doing this that I'm missing ? I'd like to avoid any hacks like returning extra text in the name, to force it to be a string.

I'm using PHP 7 and .NET 6

Many thanks

Comment: What's wrong with looping over the resultset and manually casting required values?

Comment: I would wonder why your MySQL query is returning floats as strings.

Comment: @Sammitch because of possible conversion errors.

Comment: Do you have an example of the JSON returned by the .NET? It seems like the numbers are stored as strings already which is wrong. By default PHP will encode to the next possible json type meaning if you have in `int` in PHP it will encode to `Number` in json and vice versa.

Comment: `json_encode()` is a very simple tool that can only use the original type or cast numeric strings to numbers. It doesn't have a setting to make custom manipulations depending on key name or other criteria. You'll need to do a bit of preprocessing with `$resultArray`.

Comment: @Sammitch - the query isn't returning floats as strings. The default json encoding is encoding *everything* as a string if I don't use JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK.

If I do, then names that are numeric get sent as ints rather than strings.

Comment: @CodeSpirit - I'm getting raw data back from a MySQL query, so the PHP is not using classes.

Comment: `json_encode()` does _not_ change the data type by default. https://3v4l.org/cH2QU The data you're retrieving from your query is not in the format that you require, and you must address that.

Comment: @Sammitch - thanks for your input. I was all about figuring out why the JSON wasn't being created correctly when I should have been looking at the data I was serialising, so, I went back to figure out why everything coming back from the MySQL query was in arrays of strings.

I was using PDO, but I have switched it over to use mysqli now and the MySQL is returning data in the format of the column. 

I've now removed the JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK from the json encoding and it's now doing exactly what it should.

Comment: Honestly, if PDO is doing that it's likely because something has set `PDO:ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES` to `true` somewhere, rather than being a default feature of PDO.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to know which items you want as not strings and decide what type you want them.  In this example `id` will be an `int` and `score` will be a `float`:

```
array_walk($resultArray, function(&$v) { 
                             $v['id']    = (int)$v['id'];
                             $v['score'] = (float)$v['score']; 
                         });
```

Comment: That's what I feared - I was hoping to avoid walking through the array, as there may be many thousands of records, :(